# thymeleaf Property or field cannot be found on null

Tags: thymeleaf

if `${object}` is null, then its items visited by `*{item}` would cause:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'item' cannot be found on null
```

So how to solve this and I want to have the div structure remained, like in the following example, when `currentUser` is null, `div` containing city and name remains.

```
<div class="form" th:object="${currentUser}">
     <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
          <label>city:</label>
          <span id="details_city" th:text="*{address == null ? '' : address.city}">Hongkong</span>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
          <label>name:</label>
          <span id="details_username" th:text="*{name}">Jane</span>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen such a situation in a project (but not a spring project). The approach was that all users, even anonymous (not authenticated), were represented by a *User* (e.g. or *CurrentUser*) instance. This instance was mostly empty for anonymous users. The idea was to get rid of null checks. There was a dedicated method in the *User* class that answered if the represented user is authenticated or not. IMO the approach worked decently in the context of the technology stack that was used.

If feasible in for your project you may also try the idea. You may create an empty `currentUser` instance for anonymous users. Then `currentUser` will never be null. But if you use spring security + thymeleaf security dialect you may use thymeleaf to determine if the user is anonymous if this is necessary. E.g. a sample logout link visible for logged in users only may be rendered like this:

```
<li sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
      <a href="#" class="log-out-link">
         <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Log out
      </a>
</li>
```

A `@ControllerAdvice` and `@ModelAttribute` may push the user representation in all relevant views. Alternatively you may provide a separate, empty user in the view and use something like  `th:object="${#objects.nullSafe(currentUser,emptyUser)}"`

If this is too much then do not use the `th:object` and add some extra checks.

Comment: I would be back when I try your idea.  :)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you've got two options:

- Pass an object instance anyway (with null values for the fields) or
- Duplicate your div structure, one with th:if="${object != null}" and one with th:if="${object == null}